# Upload multiple files from multiple folders to SharePoint online using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Fairly new to both SharePoint online and Powershell and thought this would be a pretty simple task, but I'm reaching out for help.

I have a client who has photos stored in multiple folders in a file share and they want to move this to SharePoint. They want to use the folder name of where the file exits as metadata to make searching easier.

This is the script I am using and not having much luck.

```
$connection = Connect-PnPOnline https://somecompany.sharepoint.com -Credentials $me -ReturnConnection 

$files = Get-ChildItem "F:\some data" -Recurse

foreach ($file in $files)
  {Add-PnPFile -Path $file.FullName -Folder Photos -Values @{"Title" = $file.Name;} -Connection $connection}
```

Issue I am having, is that this does not recurse the folders and comes back with " Local file not found"

If I can get that working, I can move onto getting the current folder name as a variable into metadata.

I'm pretty sure that this will be a simple task for experts, but alas that I am not.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Jassen

Comment: so ... what is NOT working as expected? [*grin*] it looks like your metadata is in the `-Values` parameter input ... and that only shows the file name, not the folder the file is in. do you want the ENTIRE dir name or just the immediate parent dir name?

Comment: Two things I can't get working sorry.

I cannot get it to recurse and upload all files under a series of folders. I don't need to replicate the folders, just all files under those folders into a single library.

And second, I can't get the nesting (or in fact the variables) right to use the current folder as metadata.

Comment: `$File.Directory.Name` will give you the name of the containing dir without the higher level part of the path. ///// it looks like you need to specify a `-Folder` to put the files in one folder on sharepoint. ///// as may be apparent, i have no access to sharepoint ... i'm just readin he MSDocs site info. [*grin*]

Comment: one additional point ... you likely otta add those two points to your OP so others will see them & not nag you about it. [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks Lee.  I've updated my original question.

In terms of the -Folder, that is there already and if I manually add a subfolder to the path and remove the -Recurse, the upload is working. 

Testing the directory name now.

Comment: have you tried writing out the entire line - not running it, just wrapping it in `Write-Host "Add-PnPFile <the rest of the line with double quotes swapped to single quotes>". your error msg indicates that the `-Path` parameter is not getting what it expects.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me, so will answer this. Happy for comments if there is an easier way or cleaner and also if anyone knows how to go 1 more layer deeper.

```
$connection = Connect-PnPOnline https://somecompany.sharepoint.com -Credentials $me -ReturnConnection
$LocalFolders = get-childitem -path "c:\test" | where-object {$_.Psiscontainer} | select-object FullName

foreach ($folder in $localfolders) {

$files = get-childitem -Path $folder.FullName -Recurse 

foreach ($file in $files) {

$value1 = $file.Directory.Name

Add-PnPFile -Path $file.FullName -Folder Photos -Values @{"Title" = $file.Name;"SubCat" = $value1;} -Connection $connection 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try below script, you need install [pnp powershell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/releases).

```
function UploadDocuments(){
Param(
        [ValidateScript({If(Test-Path $_){$true}else{Throw "Invalid path given: $_"}})] 
        $LocalFolderLocation,
        [String] 
        $siteUrl,
        [String]
        $documentLibraryName
)
Process{
        $path = $LocalFolderLocation.TrimEnd('\')

        Write-Host "Provided Site :"$siteUrl -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "Provided Path :"$path -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "Provided Document Library name :"$documentLibraryName -ForegroundColor Green

          try{
                $credentials = Get-Credential

                Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -CreateDrive -Credentials $credentials

                $file = Get-ChildItem -Path $LocalFolderLocation -Recurse
                $i = 0;
                Write-Host "Uploading documents to Site.." -ForegroundColor Cyan
                (dir $path -Recurse) | %{
                    try{
                        $i++
                        if($_.GetType().Name -eq "FileInfo"){
                          $SPFolderName =  $documentLibraryName + $_.DirectoryName.Substring($path.Length);
                          $status = "Uploading Files :'" + $_.Name + "' to Location :" + $SPFolderName
                          Write-Progress -activity "Uploading Documents.." -status $status -PercentComplete (($i / $file.length)  * 100)
                          $te = Add-PnPFile -Path $_.FullName -Folder $SPFolderName
                         }          
                        }
                    catch{
                    }
                 }
            }
            catch{
             Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
            }

  }
}


UploadDocuments -LocalFolderLocation C:\Lee\Share -siteUrl https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Developer -documentLibraryName MyDOc4
```